# Room DataBase not implemented

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am trying out the new Room ORM from googles Android Architecture Components, I followed the documentation but when i run my code i get `java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.zeyad.usecases.app.UserDatabase. UserDatabase_Impl does not exist`

Here is my code:

Gradle project:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
}
```

Gradle module:

```
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

User:

```
@Entity(tableName = "User")
public class User {

    static final String LOGIN = "login";
    private static final String ID = "id", AVATAR_URL = "avatar_url";
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName(LOGIN)
    @ColumnInfo(name = LOGIN)
    String login;

    @SerializedName(ID)
    @ColumnInfo(name = ID)
    int id;

    @SerializedName(AVATAR_URL)
    @ColumnInfo(name = AVATAR_URL)
    String avatarUrl;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String login, int id, String avatarUrl) {
        this.login = login;
        this.id = id;
        this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(User user) {
        return user == null || (user.login == null && user.avatarUrl == null);
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAvatarUrl() {
        return avatarUrl;
    }

    public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
        this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        return id == user.id && (login != null ? login.equals(user.login) : user.login == null
                && (avatarUrl != null ? avatarUrl.equals(user.avatarUrl) : user.avatarUrl == null));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = login != null ? login.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + id;
        result = 31 * result + (avatarUrl != null ? avatarUrl.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

UserDatabase:

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class UserDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract RoomBaseDao roomBaseDao();
}
```

RoomBaseDao:

```
@Dao
public interface RoomBaseDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertItemsReplace(User... objects);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void updateItemsReplace(User... objects);

    @Delete
    void deleteItem(User object);
}
```

Application onCreate:

```
UserDatabase gDb = Room.databaseBuilder(this, UserDatabase.class, "test-db").build(); // throws the exception above
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It feels like the code is not getting generated as expected. Did you include both dependencies in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: i updated the question with the gradle dependencies

Comment: OK, that looks fine. If you go into your module's `build/generated/source/` directory, do you see an `apt/debug/` directory with your `UserDatabase_Impl.java` and `RoomBaseDao_Impl.java` classes (in the appropriate Java package)?

Comment: i have this directory but its empty

Comment: That's the crux of the issue, then. Assuming that cleaning and rebuilding the project does not help, check your Gradle Console and see if there are any messages from the annotation processor that might explain why your code is not being generated.

Comment: yea cleaning the project and rebuilding doesnt solve, so what i can do now ?

Comment: As I wrote, check your Gradle Console and see if there are any messages from the annotation processor that might explain why your code is not being generated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145064/discussion-between-zeyad-gasser-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case I was using old version of **ButterKnife** which required `android-apt` plugin. So I updated **ButterKnife** (which now uses annotation processor) and removed plugin declaration in **Gradle** file.

Probably that was not exactly your problem, but maybe it will help others.

Comment: turns out i was still using android-apt and when i removed it, everything is working fine now.

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing which may cause the problem:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
  }
}
```